# PyCharm node.js does not exists although it is installed in Path (Windows)

Tags: python, node.js, pycharm

I have installed Node.js and it works fine when I run it from the command line on all paths. I ran `npm version` on the cmd and it worked fine.

But when I run the same `npm version` in PyCharm it says it doesn't exists although it is in the system's Path...

```
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The same things happens when I try to run Node.js cmd subproccess command...

```
'tr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I think it comes from the same problem that Node.js doesn't exists on PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings....

Check the Node.js configuration is correct like the flowing:

[image]

**Note**: Install the [node.js extension](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098-node-js) firstly  (Or search the extension from IDE settings > plugins)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, are you using Pycharm Professional? Or do you need to do another step in order to see the Nose.js option because I have: Markdown, Restructed Text and Schemas and DTDs instead

Comment: plz see my edited.

Comment: Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (PyCharm 2020.1.5)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is to copy the Node.js files from `C:\Porgram files\nodejs` to the PyCharm's project's path and then restart the Ide